# Pourquoi est-ce que « mode » a pu évoluer vers « modalité » ?

Tags: étymologie

L'anglais *modality* vient du français *modalité* :

> [modality (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=modality&searchmode=none)
>       1610s, from Old French ***modalité*** or directly from Medieval Latin modalitatem (nominative modalitas) "a being modal," from *modalis* (see [modal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=modal&allowed_in_frame=00)). Related: Modalities.

En français je considère [*mode*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mode) (au masculin) et les acceptions de [*modalité*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/modalite) qui ont trait à la linguistique et celles qui ressemblent à celles de « mode ».

Mes questions sont les suivantes :

1. Puisque son étymon « mode » existait déjà, pourquoi est-ce que « modalité » a été créé et conservé ? Qu'est-ce qui manquait à « mode » ?
2. « Modalité » est-il un dérivé superflu de « mode » ? Je ne percevrais aucune différence si les définitions considérées (pas seulement linguistiques) de « modalité » étaient transférées vers « mode » et si « modalité » était retiré du lexique français (d'où est tiré l'anglais « modality »).

Comment: Je ne m'apercevrais d'aucune différence si l'on replaçait "pas bon" et "mauvais" par un unique terme "inbon", "vraiment pas bon" et "très mauvais" par un unique terme "plusinbon", "très bon" et "meilleur" par "plusbon"... Par l'élimination des presque-synonymes, on obtiendrait au final une langue plus pratique à utiliser, et qui ne permettrait d'exprimer que ce qu'il est utile d'exprimer, ce qui serait un avantage pour tous. Je propose qu'on appelle cette nouvelle langue révolutionnaire "novlangue" :-)

Comment: @Eusebius: Ça m'a fait sourire, mais avant les modifications qui ont changé le sens des phrases, je ne crois pas que la question était aussi mal posée.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : il ne fallait bien sûr voir mon commentaire que comme une simple boutade (d'un goût qui est ce qu'il est) et pas comme une critique.

Comment: @Eusebius: Il va falloir expliquer ça au ministère de la Vérité mon cher!

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Le commentaire de Eusebius était là avant les modifs. ;-) Et même  après les clarifications, la question me paraît toujours aussi peu interprétable avec tant de présupposés étranges sur la structure du lexique.

Answer (score 1):

En se focalisant sur le sens premier<sup>1</sup> de ces deux mots :

***Modalité***

> *Propriété* que possède la substance d'avoir des modes.

- Parmi les emplois : Selon les modalités de ...

Elle reflète *la forme particulière* d'un acte, d'un fait, d'un pensée, d'un être ou d'un objet (synonymes : circonstance, manière, particularité, voire formule).

***Mode***

> *Manière d'être* d'une substance ; en logique : contingence, possibilité, impossibilité nécessité.

Les synonymes ne sont signalés que pour *Mode de*.

- Parmi les emplois : À la mode de ...

Bien sûr il y a des cas où l'on doit pouvoir remplacer un mot pour l'autre, mais leur usage est bien distinct,

- la première référence une abstraction, une propriété,
- le second un comportement.

Sur le problème de l'emploi en *linguistique* le domaine d'application n'est pas le même, et l'on conserve les notions de propriété et de comportement :

- *Modalité* est lié à la grammaire : « Adverbe de modalité » (ou adverbe de phrase) : adverbe qui modifie le sens d'un phrase entière.
- *Mode* est lié à la linguistique : Caractère d'une forme verbale susceptible d'exprimer l'attitude du sujet parlant vis-à-vis du processus exprimé par le verbe... « Les modes d'un verbe, les temps de chaque mode. Modes personnels ; impersonnel (infinitif, participe) ».

## Réponse aux questions

1. - Il ne manque rien à *mode*, qui se contente de représenter un comportement ancré (et aussi *encré*) dans une réalité.
2. - En retirant *modalité* du dictionnaire français vous empêcheriez de formuler un concept au pays de Descartes !

En cherchant le second mot *pauvre* sur cette *[page](http://academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue)* vous comprendrez pourquoi j'ai un profond respect pour ceux qui se donnent la peine d'étudier le français !

---

*<sup>1 - Références puisées dans le petit Robert</sup>*

Comment: +1. Merci. Où réfèrez-vous par `le second pauvre sur cette page`?

Comment: @LePressentiment dans le § "Anglicismes et autres emprunts".